# What will be function prototype header of the following function?

Tags: c

I m getting "Function 'searchEntry' should have a prototype" error while compiling!

Function is

```
int searchEntry(indexs ind[],char key[],int n)
```

where `indexs ind[ ]` is struct

```
typedef struct index
{
  int id;
  char word[20];
  int  count;
}indexs;
```

searchEntry Function

```
int searchEntry(indexs ind[],char key[],int n)
{
indexs *i;
for(i=ind;i<ind+n;i++)
 {
 if((strcmp(i->word,key)==0))
    {
     return(i-ind);
    }
 }
return -1;
}
```

What should be the function prototype?

Comment: The important thing to remember here is that the prototype (or definition) have to come *before* you use the function. This is because in C and C++ all names (identifiers) have to be declared before they are used. A function prototype is the *declaration* of a function.

Comment: It appears you don't yet understand what a prototype *is*, since you provided the prototype in the question.

Comment: Do not edit the question to ask a new question.  Start a new question.

Comment: I m getting this error, "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more."

Answer (score 2):

the function prototype is the same as the function definition. so it will be:

```
int searchEntry(indexs ind[],char key[],int n);
```

Comment: Now I m getting "indexs cannot start a parameter declaration" error.

Comment: @AndyK And you defined the type-alias `indexs` *before* the function prototype?

Comment: @AndyK the index stuct type definition should be defined before the prototype

Comment: How to get rid of it? wait I 'll re-edit my post with the function.

Comment: @AndyK where you have declared the prototype?

Comment: @mohamed before struct type definition!

Comment: @AndyK You have to declare things in the right order; the function prototype depends on knowing that `indexs` is a type, so you have to at least forward declare the struct before the function prototype.

Comment: -1 *the function prototype is the same as the function definition* **NO**. It's the same as the function declaration, not its definition.

Answer (score 1):

Either

```
int searchEntry(indexs ind[],char key[],int n);
```

or

```
int searchEntry(indexs [],char [],int );
```